# 64-bit 12.04 with mtp phone

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ppa

On my Ubuntu Precise 32-bit PCs, I added a PPA as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The 32-bit PCs then work fine on picking up my Android ICS phone (connected as mtp through USB cable). 
However, on my 64-bit PC, it does not pick up that phone. `lsusb` shows that it's connected OK. 
The PPA's owner says that the PPA is fine and suggests installing the 64-bit packages if they are not present.
 I've done that with no improvement. I've also tried purging the PPA and reinstalling. 
The PPA's owner also says

> "Now that 13.10 is out with all of this functionality in it, I'm not
>   doing anything new with the PPA."

. 

I have no intention of upgrading from an LTS to a non-LTS release. Any ideas please?

Comment: After installing `mtp-tools` try to connect you android phone in USB 3.0 port rather than connecting it to USB 2.0 port.

Comment: No USB 3.0 port on PC.

Comment: a port with blue tongue.